# Inserting an End-of-Line character in FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, sqlite

After retrieving rows from a SQLite DB I have to write each row to a file in External Storage. So that I can later process each row I need to insert an EOL character at the end of each row of data written.
Here is my code which does not do this.

```
fos = context.openFileOutput(outFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);            
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
for (Iterator it = _list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            bw.write((it.next().toString()));
            bw.write("\n");
            rcdsWritten++;
}
```

The list is a simple ArrayList into which the DB rows are stored.
Also, is the use FileOutputStream and BufferedWriter the right way to go about this.

Comment: Instead of capturing rows in a list and then writing each list item to file one by one, why don't you create a stringbuffer and then write the whole thing at once into a file ? It will be more I/O effective.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that approach.